# ElasticSearch UI filter from 0 is not working

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch, elastic-search-ui

I have an issue with filters on ElasticSearch UI. I'm using this version `"@elastic/react-search-ui": "^1.2.0"`. It's bit old version but I'm not able to update it. Whatever, the problem is when I want to add range filter to query it's not working as expected. Here is the filters section from my query.

```
"filters": {
    "all": [
      {
        "all": [
          {
            "sale_price": {
              "from": 0,
              "to": 100
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
```

When I perform this filter, all rows retrieves from the elastic server. If I change `from` value 0 to 1. It's working correctly. I just want to get 0 valued documents. How should I change my filter ? Or do I have to make a configuration adjustment ? I didn't find anything tangible in the provided docs.

I'll much appreciate if someone give me an advice.

By the way I'm using ReactJs version of elastic-search-ui.

Comment: Could this help https://discuss.elastic.co/t/filter-search-by-date-in-search-ui/258929/3

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately I already use setFilter function for the set the filters. The problem seems only related with `from` value. When I change it with "1" it's working properly. But I can't see 0 valued rows.